# fastest way to insert list mysql

Tags: python, mysql, list, runtime

I have a list of datetime data in python. I have a table in a SQL database that has two columns, an empty `Date_Time` column and an `ID` column. The `ID` column simply increases as 1,2,3 etc. The number of table rows is the same as the length of the datetime list. I insert the list of datetime data into the table fairly simply through the following code:

```
def populate_datetime(table, datetimes):
    sql = cnxn.cursor()
    for i in range(1, len(datetimes)+1):
        query = '''
        update {0}
        set Date_Time = '{1}' 
        where ID = {2};'''.format(table, datetimes[i-1], i) 
        sql.execute(query)
```

`table` is the name of the table in the sql database, and `datetimes` is the list of datetime data.

This code works perfectly, but the data is lengthy, approximately 800,000 datetimes long. As a result, the code takes approx. 16 minutes to run on average. Any advice on how to reduce the run time?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python+MySQL - Bulk Insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482004/pythonmysql-bulk-insert)